# How to return an array after adding and then sorting it in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have below piece of code,
What I am trying to do is add a new record at the 0th position and then sort the array based on the label. But I can't get it to work; I am getting an empty array.

```
const array = [{id: '3', name: 'name1'},
                {id: '4', name: 'name2'},
               {id: '5', name: 'name3'}]

const items = array
      .map((sp) => ({ label: sp.name, value: sp.id }))
      .splice(0, 0, { label: '', value: '' })
      .sort((a, b) => a.label - b.label);

console.log(items);
```

Comment: Did you try `console.log(array);`?

Comment: Check what array.splice returns - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: @ScottHunter It prints the original array without inserting anything :(

Comment: The way that your chaining works is:  sort is applied to the return value of splice, which is applied to the return value of map.  The return value of splice isn’t what you think it is, so the whole thing breaks.

Comment: @James How should I go about it?

Comment: Just don't chain the methods. `map()` the array into `items`, push your new object (no need to `splice()` since you're just going to sort anyway) and then call `sort()` on `items`.

Comment: @pilchard Then the resultant array is `[Object { label: "name1", value: "3" }, Object { label: "name2", value: "4" }, Object { label: "name3", value: "5" }, Object { label: "", value: "" }]` but, I need the empty one to be the first record and then sort others.

Comment: Map, sort, add item to front of array either with array.unshift or concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
const array = [
    { id: '3', name: 'name1' },
    { id: '4', name: 'name2' },
    { id: '5', name: 'name3' }
]

const items = array.map((sp) => ({ label: sp.name, value: sp.id }))
items.unshift({ label: '', value: ''})
items.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);

console.log(items);
```

Output:

```
[
  { label: '', value: '' },
  { label: 'name1', value: '3' },
  { label: 'name2', value: '4' },
  { label: 'name3', value: '5' }
]
```

Method `unshift` here is used to add a new value at the beginning of the list. Both [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) works [in place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) therefore they do not return the modified array and update the existing variable instead.

Answer (score -3):

The error in this code is that the .splice() method returns an array containing the removed items, and does not modify the original array. So, the original array is not modified when .splice() is called on it. To fix this, you can assign the return value of .splice() to the original array:

```js
const array = [{id: '3', name: 'name1'},
{id: '4', name: 'name2'},
{id: '5', name: 'name3'}]

const items = array
      .map((sp) => ({ label: sp.name, value: sp.id }))
      .splice(0, 0, { label: '', value: '' })
      .sort((a, b) => a.label - b.label);

array = items;

console.log(array);
```

Comment: There is an error on the page. and both arrays still return empty.